AddVideoEncoderConfiguration in ONVIF media20
I've a device that has a profile without a video encoder in it. I want to add it via ONVIF API. I know media wsdl (https://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl/media.wsdl) has the AddVideoEncoderConfiguration  message, but the media2.0 (https://www.onvif.org/ver20/media/wsdl/media.wsdl) has not.
My device has the media2.0 so I need a message to add the video encoder to the profile.

Ref: https://www.onvif.org/ver20/media/wsdl/media.wsdl
You should use AddConfiguration Interface in Media2 WSDL with type input as VideoEncoder available from the defined enum list tr2:ConfigurationEnumeration
<xs:simpleType name="ConfigurationEnumeration">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="All"/>           <!-- For matching all configurations -->
                <xs:enumeration value="VideoSource"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="VideoEncoder"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="AudioSource"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="AudioEncoder"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="AudioOutput"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="AudioDecoder"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="Metadata"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="Analytics"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="PTZ"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="Receiver"/>
                <!-- Vendors may conceptually add items here prefixing them with there own namespace -->
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>

